# How much time it may take to get 2000 records in Single shot with Node and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

This question is for performance analysis.

Say there are **2340** employee Documents in a `MongoDB` Collection and I have a simple Node Route and Controller method to fetch all employees data.

This is what each Employee Document look likes :

```
{
      "_id": "5839788169ad7926264b6bd3",
      "employeeId": "00003",
      "employeefirstname": "Jason",
      "employeemiddlename" : "",
      "employeelastname": "Statham",
      "dateofjoining": "1999-04-01 00:00:00",
      "designation": "Senior Manager - Customer Support",
      "qualification": ""
}
```

I am using `Mongoose` library in Node for query operations. Following is the method :

```
exports.getProjectedFields = function (req, res) {
    var employeeProjection = {
        employeeId: 1,
        employeefirstname: 1,
        employeelastname: 1,
        dateofjoining: 1,
        designation: 1,
        qualification: 1
    };

    EmployeeModel.find()
        .select(employeeProjection)
        .exec(function (err, result) {
            if (err)res.send('400', {message: 'Unable to fetch employees data. Please try again later'});

            res.jsonp(result);
        });
};
```

Response time for fetching all **2340** Documents is : `230ms` (230 milli seconds).

**Is this ideal response time in Node with Mongo or it can still be better ?**

According to the feedback that i have got from my peers, performance can be very much better and it left me in confusion to see if i have done any mistake in code. After much code walk through dint find anything as such. Please help me out.

NOTE : I have tried querying data without `Projection / Select` but dint see any performance difference.

Comment: Whats the network latency b/w server and mongo, and client and server?

Comment: @hyades Its a MEAN stack web app and still in development mode - so both Client n server are in local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cursor ? It use stream and will start to send the response while retrieving document.

```
var findCursor= EmployeeModel.find(mongoquery).cursor();

res.header("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
var first = true;
res.write("["); 
findCursor.on("data", function(data) {
    var str = ",";
    if(first == true)
    {
        first = false;
        str = "";
    }
    res.write(str+JSON.stringify(data));
});

findCursor.on("error", function(err) {
    res.write("]");
    res.end();
});
findCursor.on("end", function(err) {
    res.write("]");
    res.end();
});
```